# how to send command in console, from test Playwright js

Tags: javascript, console, playwright

Need to send a command to the console '$gui.dispatch('callBarcodeHandler', '98783083')' from test.
For example, in the test I log in and I need to send a command to scan the barcode.

Answer (score 1):

Using `page.evaluate` function you can execute an arbitrary code inside the Browser context a.k.a console

Example:

```
const windowHeight = await page.evaluate('window.innerHeight');
```

More info:
https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating